# How to work with images to overcome RAM issues in Google colab

Tags: python, database, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I've been trying out Google Colab to work on Python notebooks. The virtual machines that Colab is running on have only 27 GB of RAM. The data sets we work with require more.
I don't know if there is a way to code
Is there a way to increase the RAM available for Colab laptops?

```
def create_dataset(data_df):
# Declared Empty Lists to store the features, labels values.
features = []
labels = []
labels_1 = []
labels_2 = []
labels_3 = []
labels_4 = []
video_paths = data_df["video_name"].unique()
for video in video_paths:
    directory = "images/" + video
    frames = os.listdir(directory)
    number_frames = len(frames)
    df = data_df[data_df.video_name == video]
    ped_df = df["id_ped"].unique()
    for id_ped in ped_df:
        ped = df[df.id_ped == id_ped]
        # Calculate the the interval after which frames will be added to the list.
        skip_frames_window = int(len(ped)/SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
        for j in range(skip_frames_window):
            # Declare a list to store video frames.
            pedestrian_list = []
            for i in range(len(ped)):
                if ((i>=SEQUENCE_LENGTH*j) and i <((SEQUENCE_LENGTH*(j+1)))):
                    #print(f"i = {i}")
                    fr = ped["frame"].values.tolist()[i]
                    frame = frames[fr]
                    x1 = ped["x1"].values.tolist()[i]
                    y1 = ped["y1"].values.tolist()[i]
                    x2 = ped["x2"].values.tolist()[i]
                    y2 = ped["y2"].values.tolist()[i]
                    out1 = ped["out1"].values.tolist()[i]
                    out2 = ped["out2"].values.tolist()[i]
                    out3 = ped["out3"].values.tolist()[i]
                    out4 = ped["out4"].values.tolist()[i]
                    frame_path = f"{directory}/{frame}"
                    result = pedestrian_extraction(frame_path, x1, y1, x2, y2)
                    # Append the normalized frame into the frames list
                    pedestrian_list.append(result)
            
            features.append(pedestrian_list)
            labels_1.append(out1)
            labels_2.append(out2)
            labels_3.append(out3)
            labels_4.append(out4)
labels = [np.array(labels_1),np.array(labels_2),np.array(labels_3),np.array(labels_4)]
return np.array(features), labels

print('[INFO] loading data...')
train_features, train_labels = create_dataset(train_df)
val_features, val_labels = create_dataset(val_df)
test_features, test_labels = create_dataset(test_df)
```

This is what I get
[image]

Comment: yes of course, you can use generator, loading chunk of data at a time, and using `fit_generator` later on with your model, here is an example with explanation https://www.kaggle.com/code/vbookshelf/python-generators-to-reduce-ram-usage-part-2/notebook

Comment: Use `flow_from_directory()` and then use `fit()`. `fit_generator` is deprecated.